# Implement a jump function

Tags: antlr4, scripting-language

I'm trying to create an interpreter for my scripting language using ANTLR4. I have yet implemented the standard operations (mul, div, sub, etc...) using visitors and now i've to implement a jump \ Salta function call. *Jump(n)* FunctionCall ignore   *n* rows after his call. Example:

```
Fai var1 = 3,var2 = 4;
Fai Salta(1);    //my jump() function call
Fai var1=4;
println(var1);

output: 3
```

This is my current grammar:

```
grammar TL;
@members{
int salta=0;
}
parse
: block+ EOF
;

block
: DO statement (','statement )* END // Fai a=2,B=e;
; //manca l'if

DO:'Fai';
END:';';
Salta:'Salta';
statement
:assign
|functionCall
|saltaCall
;
functionCall
: Identifier '(' exprList? ')' #identifierFunctionCall
| Println '(' expr? ')' #printlnFunctionCall
| Print '(' expr ')' #printFunctionCall
;
saltaCall
:Salta '(' Number ')' rows[$Number.int]
;
rows[int n]
locals[int i=0;]
:({$i<$n}?END? block {$i++;})*
;

exprList
: expr (',' expr)*
;
assign
:Identifier '=' expr
;

Identifier
: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
;

expr
: '-'expr   #unaryMinusExpr
| '!'expr   #notExpr
| expr '^' expr #powerExpr
| expr '*' expr #multiplyExpr
| expr '/' expr #divideExpr
| expr '%' expr #modulusExpr
| expr '+' expr #addExpr
| expr '-' expr #subtractExpr
| expr '>=' expr #gtEqExpr
| expr '<=' expr #ltEqExpr
| expr '>' expr #gtExpr
| expr '<' expr #ltExpr
| expr '==' expr #eqExpr
| expr 'O' expr #orExpr
| expr 'E' expr #andExpr
| expr '=' expr #eqExpr
| Number        #numberExpr
| Bool          #boolExpr
| Null          #nullExpr
| functionCall   #functionCallExpr
| Identifier    #identifierExpr
| String        #stringExpr
| '(' expr ')'  #exprExpr
;
Println:'println';
Print:'print';

Null:'null';

Or : 'O';
And : 'E';
Equals : '==';
NEquals : '!=';
GTEquals : '>=';
LTEquals : '<=';
Pow : '^';
Excl : '!';
GT : '>';
LT : '<';
Add : '+';
Subtract : '-';
Multiply : '*';
Divide : '/';
Modulus : '%';
OBrace : '{';
CBrace : '}';
OBracket : '[';
CBracket : ']';
OParen : '(';
CParen : ')';
Assign : '=';
QMark : '?';
Colon : ':';


Bool
: 'true'
| 'false'
;
Number
: Int ('.' Digit*)?
;


String
: ["] (~["\r\n] | '\\\\' | '\\"')* ["]
| ['] (~['\r\n] | '\\\\' | '\\\'')* [']
;



fragment Int
: [1-9] Digit*
| '0'
;
fragment Digit
: [0-9]
;
fragment NL
: '\n'
;

// ---------SKIP------------
Comment
: ('#' ~[\r\n]* ) -> skip
;
Space
: [ \t\r\n\u000C] -> skip
;
```

How can I implement that function?

Comment: I'd make `SaltaCall` a parser rule, i.e. `saltaCall`, so you can access it's parts (i.e. `Number`).

Comment: thanks for the Comment!! now, how can i ignore the n blocks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to have a look at my [Mu interpreter](https://github.com/bkiers/Mu). Your `jump` call would look a lot like a `log` call:

```
jump
 : JUMP expr SCOL
 ;

JUMP : 'jump';
```

Then override the `visitJump` method and keep track of the value inside the `jump(...)` call inside your `EvalVisitor`.

Now all you would need to do is override the `visitBlock` method and if the recorded value inside value inside the `jump(...)` is more then 0, don't visit the next expression. Some pseudo code:

```
public class EvalVisitor extends MuBaseVisitor<Value> {

    ...

    private Double jumpAmount = 0.0;

    @Override
    public Value visitBlock(@NotNull MuParser.BlockContext ctx) {

        for (MuParser.StatContext statContext : ctx.stat()) {

            if jumpAmount is more than 0, decrease by 1
            else visit (execute) statContext
        }

        return Value.VOID;
    }

    @Override
    public Value visitJump(@NotNull MuParser.JumpContext ctx) {

        Value amount = this.visit(ctx.expr());

        jumpAmount = amount.asDouble();

        return amount;
    }

    ...
}
```